# JSON list of dictionaries to python

Tags: python, json

My json file is a list of dictionaries
[image]

I am able to successfully open it but I am not sure how to access the "the_dict" dictionary so I can retrieve and print just "test" and "pie" in my python program.

```
with open('my_settings.json') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

# my_words = config["the_dict"] is what I tried but this does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config_file` is a list, not a dictionary, as you have observed. You will need to access the first dictionary in the list, and then call the key `"the_dict"` then `"words"` to get the list of words:

```
my_words = config_file[0]["the_dict"]["words"]
```

Comment: my_words = config_file[0]["the_dict"]["words"]